# Notation of trace in QCD

Tags: notation, quantum-chromodynamics, trace

I have been reading about QCD, and I have found a notation about the trace at Schwinger Dyson equation like $Tr_D[exp]$ and I don not know whats does means. Thank you.

Update reference: equation 27
https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevC.81.065202

Comment: Perhaps you can give a reference to where you saw it. The context would make it easier to explain.

Comment: @flippiefanus Thank you! Equation 27 https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevC.81.065202

Comment: I’m going to guess that the subscript $D$ indicates a trace over the Dirac spinor indices, but if that is the case I don't know why equation 21 doesn’t use the same notation.